# Difference between org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx.x.<version_no>.jar vs org.eclipse.swt.<version_no>.jar?

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, cocoa, swt

I have always been writing code using Eclipse IDE in windows OS. I just started using Eclipse in Mac. I found these two jars when I was trying to add swt in the build path for my program. What is the difference between these two jars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SWT is built on native code, one is the interface definitions and the other is the Mac OS implementation. I'm running Linux and I have,

```
# linux specific
org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_64_3.103.0.v20140605-2012.jar
```

and

```
# cross platform Java interfaces
org.eclipse.swt_3.103.0.v20140605-2008.jar
```

and

```
# linux specific source implementing cross platform Java interfaces and  
# compilable into the first jar
org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_64.source_3.103.0.v20140605-2012.jar
```

Comment: Thanks Elliot. What do you mean by interface definitions? Because I can't see any source code inside the jar. The implementation is inside the cocoa one. Also do I need it swt.<version_no>.jar?

Comment: The [interface](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/jnigen.php) between Java and native code. It's native. Yes. You need it.

Comment: But I don't see any source code inside the jar. Also I am able to run the application without it. So I am kinda confused.

Comment: I guess then *you* don't need it. It depends on what you're doing. What application?

Comment: I mean I was just writing a program with SWT and I am able t run it without that jar.